# Using potentiometer to measure distance in linear actuator

Tags: microcontroller, current, resistors, motor, control

I need to use a linear actuator for a project. From what I understand, the position feedback comes from a potentiometer. Here is an example:

[image]

One more example: https://www.servocity.com/html/25_lbs__thrust_linear_actuator.html
[image]

Two questions:

1) How does one get the actual position via, say, a microcontroller? It looks like I need to measure resistance, I don't know how to do that on an Arduino.

2) Internally how is the linear position correlating to a potentiometer signal? Is a gear near the end of the gearbox turning a pot nob essentially?

Thank you.

Comment: Hmm no data sheet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't measure resistance, you measure voltage. Apply known voltages (like 0V and 5V) to the two "reference" lines, and measure the "signal" voltage. There's an ADC in the Arduino to do that.

Internally ... a rotary pot is one way to do it. A more accurate way would be a linear pot running the full length of the actuator. How yours works I can't say.

If you needed an accurate position you'd use digital scales like a DRO or calipers instead.

Comment: Thank you Brian that makes a lot of sense. For the measured voltage, would it be a linear relationship between voltage and actuator extended distance, with a given offset? So a straight line equation I can code in.

Comment: @JDS This would be specified in the datasheet, you probably need a few more corrections (piecewise linear), or possibly entirely nonlinear map

Comment: Linear relationship? I would be very surprised to see anything else... I wouldn't expect better than a couple of percent accuracy, and wouldn't be surprised to see 5-10% on a cheap product.

Comment: And position repeatability may be somewhat disappointing if you are looking at positions down to the .001 to 0.010 range of position. For much better repeatability you move away from an analog position sensor and look for positioners that use a linear optical scale that has digital pickups that output a quadrature waveform. A third output will provide an index pulse at one particular position (one end or center is typical) that can be homed to at startup to establish position reference.

Comment: One more question for anyone still reading. Say the supplier offers 3 potentiometer options: 1k, 5k, 10k. What are the trade-offs, and what would the practical differences be? Here's an example: http://www.aliexpress.com/item/1inch-25mm-Stroke-Position-Feeback-Linear-Actuator-With-Potentiometer-12V-DC-225lbs-Load-Capacity/32246771337.html?ws_ab_test=searchweb201556_7,searchweb201527_4_71_72_73_74_75,searchweb201560_1